# OS X tooltip duration

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I would like to extend the duration of tooltips (specifically in Safari for reading XKCD). I've seen a few plist values which allow you to adjust other aspects of tooltips such as the initial delay. Is there any way to lengthen their duration?

Comment: There's an extension for that specific problem: [xkcd Tooltip Viewer](http://squareworld.com/safari/)

Comment: Looks great, I just installed it. I'm glad I stuck that parenthetical in the question.